How to verify Gemini API Key
I´m trying to verify an Gemini API Key with python, I researched and the solution I found was this:
import subprocess
import json

def verifiy_api_key(api_key):
    comand_curl = f"""curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                     -d '{{"contents":[
                               {{"role": "user",
                                 "parts":[{{"text": "Give me five subcategories of jazz?"}}]}}]}}' \
                     "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1/models/gemini-1.0-pro:generateContent?key={api_key}" """

    result = subprocess.run(comand_curl, shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
    
    response_json = json.loads(result.stdout)
    # Verify curl sucess
    if result.check_returncode:
      #verify valid api Key
      if response_json.get("error"):
        print("Invalid Key")
        return False
      else:
        print("Valid Key")
        return True
    else:
      print("Error in curl.")
      return False
        

# Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual API key
GOOGLE_API_KEY = input('Type API Key: ')
while(verifiy_api_key(GOOGLE_API_KEY) == False):
  print("Try Again")
  GOOGLE_API_KEY = input('Type API Key: ')

My question is: "is there another best way to verify an Gemini API key? There is any short way?"
obs: Don't pay attention to bad code i´m just studying.


Do not launch a subprocess to execute curl. Write native Python code using the requests library or similar. 2) Your example will only verify that the API key has access to one Gemini model. Instead, use the list models API to determine the available models, which can be different for each Google account. Your goal is to confirm that the API key can access the desired Gemini model. 3) For security reasons, do not specify the API key via a request parameter. Use the x-goog-api-key HTTP header.


You can use this python function to validate a Google Gemini API key:
import requests

def verify_gemini_api_key(api_key):
    API_VERSION = 'v1'
    api_url = f'https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/{API_VERSION}/models?key={api_key}'
    
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    
    # Verifica si hubo un error en la respuesta
    if response.status_code != 200:
        error_message = response.json().get('error', {}).get('message', 'Invalid API key')
        raise Exception(error_message)
    
    return True



For security reasons, do not specify the API key via a request parameter. Use the x-goog-api-key HTTP header

Not sure what you're trying to do here. Google has a nice suite of libraries for developers to interface gemini in their application.
Start by reading their docs or examples here
